# Combine [FromBody] and [FromRoute] attributes in one model

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, attributes

I am trying to create model, which I could use for Body and Route at once. I found solution [here](https://www.thetechplatform.com/post/how-to-bind-fromroute-and-frombody-into-one-model-in-net-5), but I would like to move it little bit further. Not using extra "body" class, but include everything in one class. I tried this, but it does not work.

```
    public class Car
    {
        [Required, FromRoute]
        public int CarId { get; set; }

        [Required, FromBody]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required, FromBody]
        public string Colour { get; set; }

        [Required, FromBody]
        public string Wheels { get; set; }
      
        [Required, FromBody]
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to use it as input for PUT method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CarUpdate(Car car, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

[image]

But I would like to have it like this:

[image]

Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only use FromBody once, you are trying to use it multiple times , this is why is not working. This looks akward but will be working

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CarUpdate(CarRoute carRoute, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

but you will have to add this to startup

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
});
```

classes

```
 public class CarRoute
    {
        [FromRoute]
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        [FromBody]
        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
    public class Car
    { 
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So is not there another way to have everything in one model?

Comment: @JonášKowalczyk When you use frombody you can only use it once, so you can put together only very simple model. But if you use formdata content type, or form-urlencoded you can put everything in one model